# Detect element fading true or false with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, i have an element `$('#div')` and i have an event like :

```
$('#div').click(function(){
    $("#element").fadeIn();
    $("#div").addClass("closable");
});
```

Now, i have an other event, on the document :

```
$(document).click(function(){
  if($('#div').hasClass('closable')){
      $("#element").fadeOut();
  }
});
```

I need to fadeout my element when i click somewhere on the page, but only if my element has the class "closable".

In my example, when i click on my div, my element fadein and fadeout instantly... How can i do that ?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you add the class `closable` just after the fade-in animation starts, not after it has *completed*. This is because `.fadeIn` schedules the animation but returns before it has run (actually, before it has even *started*).

Fix this by taking advantage of the fact that `.fadeIn` allows you to specify a callback function that gets invoked when the animation is complete:

```
$('#div').click(function(){
    $("#element").fadeIn(function() { $("#div").addClass("closable") });
});
```

Comment: @ClémentAndraud you certainly want to remove class closable once faded out too

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [e.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) here:

```
$('#div').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $("#element").fadeIn();
    $(this).addClass("closable");
});
```

and you don't need to check `hasClass()` also, just need:

```
$(document).click(function(){
    $("#element").fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Click on on the '#div' will execute both

1- The #div click event

2- The document click event ince the '#div' is an element of the document.

To prevent this behaviour, just write

```
$('#div').click(function(e){
    $("#element").fadeIn();
    $("#div").addClass("closable");
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

to stop the event propagation to parents elements.

**UPDATE**

I see some answers relying on the event.target property to check if the #div was clicked or another element but this is a **wrong** solution.

I explain why :

if the #div element has another elements within it and the user clicks on that element.

Example :

```
<div id="div">
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <div id="nested-div'>Content goes here</div>
</div>
```

and the user clicks on the title or the #nested-div element.

In this case, `$(event.target).is('#div')` will fail.

Hope this is clear enough.